# Bandpass filter in Fourier space with Gaussian function (1D signal)

Tags: python, filtering, signal-processing, fft, gaussian

After reading around and looking at the Gaussian function, I have written the following code for FFT filtering with a Gaussian window. The data is already Fourier transformed.

I am 99% percent sure from the output this code is working as expected, but a few things were implemented with trial and error and I am a little unsure of what is actually going on at some points. Below I will post images of the data at each stage with a description of what I think is going on, and at the end ask specific questions.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.fftpack as fftpack
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.fftpack as fftpack

# Setup parameters
data = np.load(r'C:\test_fft.npy')
num_samples = len(data)
fs = 10000.0
low_hz = 1
high_hz = 200

# Generate and apply filter
freqs = fftpack.fftfreq(num_samples, 1 / fs)
plt.plot(gauss_window)

gauss_window = 1 / np.sqrt(2 * np.pi * high_hz / fs) * np.exp(-0.5 * (freqs / high_hz)**2)
plt.plot(gauss_window)

gauss_window[np.where(np.abs(freqs) < low_hz)] = 0
plt.plot(gauss_window)

filtered_data = gauss_window * data * fs
plt.plot(data)
plt.plot(filtered_data)
```

[image]

There are the frequency bins without `fftshift`, labelled with how I understand that map to the frequency range.

[image]

This is the high-pass Gaussian filter for point-multiplication with the data in Fourier space. Comparing this with the above, this looks like it will cut across from above Nyquist to max positive frequencies, which makes sense. However, it also cuts out the central area that contains the low frequencies which does not make sense to me.

[image]

Next the sections that are of frequency under the low cutoff are set to zero. Again this makes sense but mapping to the freqs output, this seems to cut off around the Nyquist frequency.

[image]

Data before and after filtering. This doesn't look how I expected, I think as the multiplication is with imaginary numbers (?).

Q) I am clearly misunderstanding something with how the output of `fftpack.fftfreq()` maps to the generated Gaussian window (e.g. why does the low-pass cutoff change around the Nyquist?)

EDIT:

Updates since comments, as you say I had completely misunderstood the order of the frequencies:

[image]

In this case, the frequency bands cover the expected portion of the spectrum. The data is generated as the deconvolution in frequency space of the data with a template.

```
data = fftpack.fft(data1)
template = fftpack.fft(template)
data /= template
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you misunderstand the meaning of the frequency axis. The negative frequencies are not the low frequencies. Low frequencies are around 0. Nyquist is in the middle of your first graph, where you have large positive and negative frequencies. The DFT (what the FFT computes) puts the origin (the zero frequency, or DC component) as the leftmost sample. Your Gaussian window is a low-pass filter, it passes unchanged the lowest frequencies only, and suppresses the medium and high frequencies.

Comment: We need to know how your input data is organized. Is it directly the output of an FFT function, or has it been modified to have the zero frequency in the middle? By looking at the plot, I would wager that this is indeed the case, since you'd expect any properly sampled signal to have little power near the Nyquist frequency.

Comment: Thanks Cris, I have edited with a little more information. This makes much more sense now. Could I confirm the frequencies are now conceptualised in correct order, and that my filter is band-pass due to the line ``` gauss_window[np.where(np.abs(freqs) < low_hz)] = 0``` (in the third plot,  the orange line that start at the x axis start one sample from each end (e.g. low cutoff 1hz) - apologies this is not very clear.

Comment: Yes, that seems right. The thing that is missing is knowing what the order of the frequencies is in the input data. This should be documented by whoever wrote that data to disk.